# Deploy SQL Database to MS Azure Storage - Error: 40804

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

Need to deploy a SQL Database to MS Azure Storage, but getting the following error:

> The service objective 'Web' specified is invalid. (Microsoft SQL
>   Server, Error: 40804)

Tried the following site: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93168/ssms-2014-deploy-database-feature-has-old-sql-azure-settings

but seems like my version is not compatible. Are there any other possible solutions?

[image]

Comment: how do you go about creating a v11 server, as I cannot seem to get this right, and cannot find online help with this. Thanks

Comment: I managed to install the database as a Data Project in Visual Studio, Set the target framework of the project to SQL Azure, and then you do a build and publish to your azure site. The so-called "duplicate" post did not resolve the issue!